# Count Always return -1 SQL Server. ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Query always return -1 don't know why. Will someone please explain. Value of count always remains -1.

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Emails FROM users";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

    try
    {
       connection.Open();
       count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

       if (count > 0)
          return "Something Wrong1";
    }
    catch
    {
       return "Something Wrong2";
    }

    return count + "Every thing ok";
 }
```

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx): For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

Comment: It's not the value of `count` that you're getting back - calling `.ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows **affected** by your SQL statement - there is nothing to affect any rows, so you get back -1. Use `.ExecuteScalar()` instead to return the one row, one column value that your query returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) does not return the result of the query, it just executes it on the SQL server. The return value is the number of rows affected by your statement, -1 when the statement does not affect any rows. `ExecuteNonQuery` (as the name implies) is not intended for returning query results, but rather for running a statement that changes data (such as INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE). The docs state:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. (...) For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

You could use:

```
count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

To get the count you are looking for. There is also an example in the [docs for `ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is sloved. Thank you everyone for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) not [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) to retrieve the count value.

Answer (score 1):

I think that perhaps what you mean is for your SQL statement to be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE Email = @email
```

Besides that, you must use the `ExecuteScalar` method to retrieve the count.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C# expert, but that `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't seem right ... it's a *query* after all!