# How to subtract time in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am taking two values from database as a string. Now I want to subtract these two values. Please help me and thanks in advance.

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label4.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        string condur = Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(condur);
        string q1 = "select in_time from in_time where car_reg='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ";

        string q2 = "select out_time from out_time where car_reg='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ";
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(q1, connection);
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(q2, connection);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string q3=command1.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();

            string q4=command2.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();



            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(q3);
            DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(q4);
            TimeSpan result = dt2 - dt1; ;
            string result1 = result.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = result1;

            //MessageBox.Show("Insertion successful!");
            //textBox1.Text = ""; textBox2.Text = ""; textBox3.Text = ""; comboBox1.Text = ""; comboBox3.Text = ""; textBox11.Text = ""; textBox6.Text = ""; textBox8.Text = ""; textBox9.Text = ""; richTextBox1.Text = ""; textBox4.Text="";
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the problem?  The code you showed will successfully subtract the values.

Comment: Okay, so what doesn't work, what is the result, are you getting exception, and in general - what is the problem?

Comment: are q3 and q4 valid data? Show us what you are getting and what you are expecting.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning although slightly off topic - or security it might be best not to take the direct value of the combo box just to help against SQL injection.

Comment: i am talking the entry time and exit time of a employee and stored tgem in 2 different table of a database.now i want to subtract the two value that r stored in database for a specific employee.bt everytime there is showing a exception.and i cant solve it up.can anu one help me in tis case.its urgent.......

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you answered your own question:

```
    TimeSpan result = dt2 - dt1;
```

To subtract two `DateTime` values in C#, you simply use the subtraction operator. If there is something wrong with the code sample you posted, you should describe the error, and what you expected to happen.

## Edit in response to comment

That exception has nothing to do with *subtracting* the dates, it has something to do with your conversion from the type *string* to the type *DateTime*. You are trying to parse from string to DateTime:

```
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(q3);
```

This fails because `q3` does not represent a valid string. The reason why, is the way you ([don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962205/13627)) query:

```
string q3=command1.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
```

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) does not return the results of the query, rather it returns the number of *changed rows*. In other words, `ExecuteNonQuery` is not intended for querying, but for update scenarios, etc.

What you probably want is to use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx), which returns a single value from the query. If the types in the DB are correct, it will come back as a `DateTime`, so you don't need to do the `DateTime.Parse` part. The relevant parts of your code would become:

```
DateTime q3 = (DateTime)command1.ExecuteScalar();
DateTime q4 = (DateTime)command2.ExecuteScalar();

TimeSpan result = q4-q3;
```

*Oh, and BTW, please look up the terms "SQL Injection", and "parameterized queries" on Google.*

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."this exception msg is showing

Comment: i am talking the entry time and exit time of a employee and stored tgem in 2 different table of a database.now i want to subtract the two value that r stored in database for a specific employee.bt everytime there is showing a exception.and i cant solve it up.can anu one help me in tis case.its urgent.......

Comment: Please see my updated answer. If you included that info to begin with, you would have gotten the answer in a matter of minutes. Don't expect people to run and debug your code here. Include all relevant info when asking.

Comment: "Specified cast is not valid."now this exception msg is showing

Comment: That means that the type in the DB is not a datetime, so the cast to DateTime fails. You probably would want to re-add DateTime.Parse, then (but still use ExecuteScalar). What is the column type in the database. ?

Comment: It makes sense to use the types in the DB (and in C#) that the data represent. That way your code will flow much better, and you don't need to worry about conversions in the majority of the code. Work on the correct data types in your code, do the needed conversions ASAP (when data is entered). I would change the type in the DB.

Comment: i dont get u.can you be more specific????in where i should convet data type.i dont get it.plzz help me.i m in a great maze

Comment: **I'd change the data type in the database**. It will save you a conversion when you save and a conversion when you read.